# How to select 2nd parent folder relative to the provided path?

Tags: php, codeigniter

In CodeIgniter, there are available defined filepath constants inside the `/public/index.php`.

There are following constants available:

- `BASEPATH` returns `C:/wamp/www/testci2_2.dev/system/`
- `SELF` returns `index.php`
- `SYSDIR` returns `system`
- `FCPATH` returns `C:\wamp\www\testci2_2.dev\public\`

Inside my controller `/application/controllers/configurations.php` within a `function backup()` method, I would like to make backup files write directly to the `/sql/` folder which is located here: `C:\wamp\www\testci2_2.dev\sql\`

I tried to use `var_dump(dirname(BASEPATH) . '/sql/');` which produces what I want, but I am not quite sure if it's the best way to do that, maybe there is smarter steps to get that path ?

How can I target that folder by using some of this constants ? 
If it is not possible, is there any other CLEVER method so when one day I decide to move controllers into the subfolders or so, they will not loose the track from specified folders ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [`pathinfo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) to extract the directory name from `FCPATH` prior to `\public\`

```
$path = pathinfo(FCPATH, PATHINFO_DIRNAME) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'sql' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
echo $path; // C:\wamp\www\testci2_2.dev\sql\
```